# Using PostgreSQL on Mac OS X Lion

Tags: macos, osx-lion, postgresql, homebrew

I just got a new Mac with Lion installed on it. I then installed Xcode (4.1 through the App Store).  Next, I installed [Homebrew](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew) and I was about to do `brew install postgresql` like I had done on Snow Leopard, but I'm reading online that PostgreSQL is already included in Lion.

Can someone confirm if this is true?  And if it is included, can I use it for my PostgreSQL server for development (Rails) or is the included PostgreSQL used for the operating system only?

Answer (score 1):

Postgres is indeed included with Lion Server... but it's so deeply tied into the OS, and hidden from view that I wouldn't really want to use it for dev use.

Set up a second instance and use that instead.  No reason to risk your ability to use things like iCal, AddressBook and Collabd over a coding error.

Comment: haven't installed it yet but found this good post https://plus.google.com/114301087219148980063/posts/VHmzi63jCJK